# Python Vector implementation that acts as a class and also a collection of staticmethods

Tags: python, object-oriented, functional-programming

Recently I've been wondering about ways of implementing objects in code that can be represented by other primitives. An example of this is a Vector, which can be represented by a Vector\$N\$D  where \$N\$ is the dimension of vector, or it can be represented by an \$N\$-tuple.

The reason this is causing me so much trouble is because I can't decide whether to provide a class that implements all the functions that can be applied to a vector as methods, or to provide a bunch of functions that aren't bounded to a class and can act upon any vector-like object (a vector class or tuple).

The code below is one solution I had to the problem (not the optimal one I don't think, just one I was messing around with). It basically implements a Vector class as an interface that can be used as a class with methods (i.e., `Vector2D(1, 2).magnitude()`) or can be used as a collection of "static methods" (using the term dubiously) to act on non Vector objects (i.e. `Vector2D.magnitude((1, 2))`).

The code I came up with feels very un-pythonic however. It requires the usage of calling methods as static methods from the class and seems kind of messy in general. What could I do to solve my dilemma whilst also making this code more pythonic?

```
import math

class VectorMeta(type):

    component_names = ('x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'u', 'v')

    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, kwargs):
        degree = kwargs.get('_degree')
        if degree:        
            for i in range(degree):
                def _getter(self, i=i):
                    return self[i]
                def _setter(self, val, i=i):
                    self[i] = val

                prop = property(fget=_getter, fset=_setter)
                kwargs[metacls.component_names[i]] = prop

        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, kwargs)

class _baseVector(metaclass=VectorMeta):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == self._degree:
            self._components = list(args)
        elif len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], (list, tuple)):
            self._components = list(args[0])
        else:
            raise ValueError("Too many components for vector of length %i." % self._degree)

    def _range(self):
        return range(len(self))

    def __len__(self):
        """
        X.__len__() <==> len(X)
        """
        return len(self._components)

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        X.__iter__() <==> iter(X)
        """
        for component in self._components:
            yield component

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
        X.__getitem__(key) <==> X[key]
        """
        return self._components[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        """
        X.__setitem__(key, val) <==> X[key] = val
        """
        self._components[key] = val

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        X.__repr__() <==> repr(X)
        """
        return "%s%s" % (
            self.__class__.__name__,
            str(tuple(self._components))
            )

    def __add__(self, other):
        """
        X.__add__(Y) <==> X + Y
        """
        _baseVector._diff_len_err(self, other, 'add')
        return self.__class__([self[i] + other[i] for i in _baseVector._range(self)])
    __radd__ = __add__

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """
        X.__sub__(Y) <==> X - Y
        """
        _baseVector._diff_len_err(self, other, 'subtract')
        return self.__class__([self[i] - other[i] for i in _baseVector._range(self)])

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        """
        X.__rsub__(Y) <==> Y - X
        """
        _baseVector._diff_len_err(self, other, 'subtract')
        return self.__class__([other[i] - self[i] for i in _baseVector._range(self)])

    def __mul__(self, other):
        """
        X.__mul__(Y) <==> X * Y
        """
        _baseVector._non_scalar_err(self, other, 'multiply')
        return self.__class__([other*self[i] for i in _baseVector._range(self)])
    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        """
        X.__truediv__(Y) <==> X / Y
        """
        _baseVector._non_scalar_err(self, other, 'divide')
        return self.__class__([self[i]/other for i in _baseVector._range(self)])

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        """
        X.__floordiv__(Y) <==> X // Y
        """
        _baseVector._non_scalar_err(self, other, 'divide')
        return self.__class__([self[i]/other for i in _baseVector._range(self)])

    add = __add__
    sub = __sub__
    mul = __mul__
    div = __truediv__
    floordiv = __floordiv__

    def cast_to_ints(self):
        """
        Cast the components of the vector to integer values.
        """
        return self.__class__([int(self[i]) for i in _baseVector._range(self)])

    def dot_product(self, other):
        """
        Calculate the dot product of two vectors.
        """
        _baseVector._diff_len_err(self, other, 'perform dot product on')
        return sum([self[i]*other[i] for i in _baseVector._range(self)])

    def magnitude(self):
        """
        Calculate the magnitude of a vector.
        """
        return math.sqrt(sum([self[i]*self[i] for i in range(len(self))]))

    def magnitude_sqrd(self):
        """
        Calculate the squared magnitude of a vector.
        """
        return sum([self[i]*self[i] for i in range(len(self))])

    def normalize(self):
        """
        Normalize a vector (find the unit vector with the same direction).
        """
        magnitude = _baseVector.magnitude(self)
        return self.__class__([self[i]/magnitude for i in range(len(self))])

    def project(self, other):
        """
        Project a vector or vector-like object onto another.
        """
        other_norm = _baseVector.normalize(other)
        a = _baseVector.dot_product(self, other_norm)
        return _baseVector.mul(other_norm, a)

    def _diff_len_err(self, other, action):
        if len(self) != len(other):
            raise ValueError("Cannot %s vectors of different "
                             "length (Got lengths %i and %i)." % \
                             (action, len(self), len(other))
                             )

    def _non_scalar_err(self, other, action):
        if other.__class__ not in {int, float}:
            raise ValueError("Cannot %s vector by non-scalar type %s." % \
                             (action, type(other))
                             )

class Vector2D(_baseVector):
    _degree = 2

    def angle_between(self, other):
        dot_prod = Vector2D.dot_product(self, other)

        mag_self = Vector2D.magnitude(self)
        mag_other = Vector2D.magnitude(other)

        return math.acos(dot_prod/(mag_self*mat_other))

    # 2D vector stuff

class Vector3D(_baseVector):
    _degree = 3

    def cross_product(self, other):
        ax, ay, az = self
        bx, by, bz = other
        return self.__class__([
            ay*bz - az*by,
            az*bx - ax*bz,
            ax*by - ay*bz
            ])

    # 3D vector stuff

class Quaternion(_baseVector):
    _degree = 4

    # Quaternion implementation stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

In its standard library, Python itself prefers using a free-ranging function that may call a method on the class. For instance, `len()` calls `o.__length__`, `str()` calls `o.__str__()`, etc.

Following this precedent, you can design your module with a `magnitude()` function that will call `o.magnitude()` method on the class, or cast it to the appropriate type when given collection objects of the appropriate length.

If you're concerned about namespacing, you can put your code in a module, so that you have:

```
vector.magnitude(x, y)
vector.magnitude(v)
vector.Vector2D(x, y).magnitude()
```

and so on.

Comment: Python already has a generic function [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs), which dispatches to the [`__abs__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__abs__) method. So it would make sense to use that instead of adding your own `magnitude` generic function.